# floats inside tuples changing values when accessed

Tags: python

So I have a list of tuples of two floats each.  Each tuple represents a range.  I am going through another list of floats which represent values to be fit into the ranges.  All of these floats are < 1 but positive, so precision matter.  One of my tests to determine if a value fits into a range is failing when it should pass. If I print the value and the range that is causing problems I can tell this much:

```
curValue = 0.00145000000671 
range = (0.0014500000067055225, 0.0020968749796738849)
```

The conditional that is failing is:

```
if curValue > range[0] and ... blah :
    # do some stuff
```

From the values given by curValue and range, the test should clearly pass (don't worry about what is in the conditional).  Now, if I print explicitly what the value of range[0] is I get:

```
 range[0] =  0.00145000000671
```

Which would explain why the test is failing.  So my question then, is why is the float changing when it is accessed.  It has decimal values available up to a certain precision when part of a tuple, and a different precision when accessed.  Why would this be?  What can I do to ensure my data maintains a consistent amount of precision across my calculations?

Comment: Are you sure `0.00145000000671` or `0.0014500000067055225` could be represented exactly as you are expecting?

Comment: @Graham Can you provide a 5-line example program that exhibits the problem? If not, the problem is probably in your code ;)

Comment: curValue > range[0] returns True on my machine...the conditional we're not supposed to worry about looks like your problem...or it's actually doing the "stuff" and you just don't realize it

Comment: @Graham: The value displayed is not necessarily the value stored. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The float doesn't change. The built-in numberic types are all immutable. The cause for what you're observing is that:

1. `print range[0]` uses `str` on the float, which (up until very recent versions of Python) printed less digits of a float.
2. Printing a tuple (be it with `repr` or `str`) uses `repr` on the individual items, which gives a much more accurate representation (again, this isn't true anymore in recent releases which use a better algorithm for both).

As for why the condition doesn't work out the way you expect, it's propably the usual culprit, the limited precision of floats. Try `print repr(curVal), repr(range[0])` to see if what Python decided was the closest representation of your float literal possible.

Comment: This was the answer that helped me find my problem.  It turns out that curValue and range[0] were actually equal even though I thought that curValue was bigger.

Answer (score 4):

In modern day PC's floats aren't that precise. So even if you enter pi as a constant to 100 decimals, it's only getting a few of them accurate. The same is happening to you. This is because in 32-bit floats you only get 24 bits of mantissa, which limits your precision (and in unexpected ways because it's in base2).

Please note, `0.00145000000671` isn't the exact value as stored by Python. Python only diplays a few decimals of the complete stored float if you use `print`. If you want to see exactly how python stores the float use `repr`.

If you want better precision use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Note that Decimals are still floating point numbers and still have limited (albeit much larger by default and adjustable) precision, it's just the same inaccuracies we're used to as it uses base 10 instead of base 2.

Comment: Python's float is C's double, so it's not a 32-bit float, but the remarks about limited precision still apply.

Comment: @delnan, python decimal module will not have such inaccuracies, it is not about base

Comment: @Anurag: It does, they're just of different from those of base 2 floats. Try `Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)` for instance - the result can't be represented in positional notation with a finite number of digits in base 10.

Comment: @delnan, that is not the point result may not represent 1/3 but whatever it represents is precise i.e Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333') and you can change precision for your usecase which is not the case with floats

Comment: @Anurag: No matter what precision you set, it must be finite and hence decimals can't represent 1/3 (among other rational numbers). Yeah, you can *usually* (I imagine there are also applications which, strictly speaking, require perfect accuracy even with irrational numbers, e.g. symbolic math) reduce the error enough to make it not matter for your application, but "accurate *enough*" isn't "accurate". And you still need to determine that threshold and set the appropriate precision.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't *changing* per se. Python is doing its best to store the data as a float, but that number is too precise for float, so Python modifies it before it is even accessed (in the very process of storing it). Funny how something so small is such a big pain.

You need to use a arbitrary fixed point module like [Simple Python Fixed Point](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Simple%20Python%20Fixed-Point%20Module/0.6) or the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it would work in this case, because I don't know if Python's limiting in the output or in the storage itself, but you could try doing:

```
if curValue - range[0] > 0 and...
```